# Column chart not showing all legends

Tags: google-visualization

I'm trying to do a chart using google api, but i have a problem on the bottom of the chart, because i want to show all bars with they respective numbers, there is my code.

I need to describe all the bars with they respective "legends".

```
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn("number", "x");
    data.addColumn("number", "y");

    for (var i = 0; i < response.x.length; i++) {       
        data.addRows([[response.x[i], response.y[i]]]);
    }

    var options = {
        colors: ["#30c0cd", "#ee5f3e"],
        title: "title"
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart($("#dholder")[0]);
    chart.draw(data, options);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your x and y axis are continuous (and not discrete) the google chart api will try to find the best values and will not show every label. Try:

```
data.addColumn("string", "x");
```